# How to import WP XML file automatically on installation?

Tags: installation, customization

I'd like the user to install WP and have the default content loaded automatically but i don't want to have to write in in PHP in the wp_install_defaults(); I'd much rather export an xml file each time i make a change to the default and just bundle that with the install.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the file wp-admin/includes/import.php, you'll find the necessary functions in there.